# Button Transition

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pythoncard

I am programming wxPython with GUI aid from pythonCard. The resource editor has made short work of my display so far.

The GUI has static boxes "cards" with information that the program outputs. I would like to transition to a different page on button click. So for example, clicking on ok should take me to page 2 (separate resource file).The complexity is I don't want to open up a new window for each click as I have 20 buttons.

I have 10 cards with same properties so on click i only want to change the particular and still be on main page however go to page two for particular card. Visually think of windows 8 tile and on click it flips to reveal more information.

Is this possible in wxPython? If so, how could i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want a Notebook or similar "book" control. The wxPython demo details the various book controls that wx supports. Or you might want to just swap panels, which is pretty easy to do as well. Here's a tutorial I wrote on the subject a while back:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

And here are a couple links on notebooks and similar controls:

- http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Notebook-class.html
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Simple%20wx.Notebook%20Example
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/wxpython-how-to-programmatically-change-wx-notebook-pages/